# Best Window Manager for One Application

Tags: centos, desktop, desktop-environment

First off:  I'm running CentOS light (If this is a bad choice, perhaps recommend one.  I'm able to switch between distros fairly easily atm) and I don't need a complicated setup, I just need to be able to run a windowed .jar file and interact using keyboard/mouse.  This is for a lightweight system (256MB, perhaps not as 'light' as others) and the application (a network slideshow browser) runs in 1280x1024.  Are there any suggestions, most searches for a lightweight window manager yield something more complicated than what I need.

Comment: If you are really using a *single* application and it opens a *single* window then you don't need a window manager at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't required to run a window manager at all.  I've setup several such applications that are meant to be the only application ever run and they are meant to run full screen and I've never used a window manager.  I always start with a server distro so a desktop and all of it's dependencies aren't loaded automatically.  Then installed X and setup custom upstart/systemd scripts to start X at boot along with a custom .xinitrc.  This sounds like it would fit your situation well.  It takes a little know-how, but it makes for a lightweight system that's very portable.

Comment: This is good advise so ling as it's a single window application. I have done this too and it works quite well.

Comment: I ended up running Arch with a custom X configuration.  I wanted to avoid using pure X as it can be finicky with input, but I managed to get it working.

Comment: I've had more problems with finicky display drivers and chipsets than input, even working with unusual touchscreens using not-so-common drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a window manager, then try fluxbox/blackbox. They are "more full" desktop environments, but they don't consume many resources.

If you want pure window manager then twm is the most lightweight. xmonad Will work great for this too.

Comment: Xmonad will work great... once you install the gigabyte of haskell packages to run it.